# xpath doesn't return any value

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I tried to use Xpath to read XML. The problem that I don't get any result from the evaluate
public class XPathUtils implements IXPath {

```
private Document doc;
private XPath xpath;

public XPathUtils(String baseString) throws HanaHttpConnectivityException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    try {
        // resolve attacks on XML parsers - Fortify issue
        docFactory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false); //$NON-NLS-1$
        docFactory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false); //$NON-NLS-1$
        docFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false); //$NON-NLS-1$
        docFactory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", false); //$NON-NLS-1$
        docFactory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", false); //$NON-NLS-1$
        docFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", true); //$NON-NLS-1$  
        docFactory.setXIncludeAware(false);
        docFactory.setValidating(false);
        docFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);

        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputStream inputs = new ByteArrayInputStream(baseString.getBytes());
        doc = docBuilder.parse(inputs);
        inputs.close();
        xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        throw new HanaHttpConnectivityException(e);
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        throw new HanaHttpConnectivityException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new HanaHttpConnectivityException(e);
    }

}

public Object getObjectValue(String strValue) throws HanaHttpConnectivityException {

    try {
        XPathExpression xpathExp = xpath.compile(strValue);
        return xpathExp.evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        throw new HanaHttpConnectivityException(e);
    }

}

public String getElementValue(String strValue) throws HanaHttpConnectivityException {

    try {
        XPathExpression xpathExp = xpath.compile(strValue);
        return xpathExp.evaluate(doc);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        throw new HanaHttpConnectivityException(e);
    }

}
```

}

The main function

```
    try {
        XPathUtils xpathUtil = new XPathUtils(metadata);
        Object commandValue = xpathUtil.getObjectValue("/edmx:Edmx/edmx:DataServices/Schema");
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) commandValue;
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
             String test2 = nodes.item(i).getNodeValue(); 
            }
```

this is the XML

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <edmx:Edmx 
        xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx">
         <edmx:DataServices 
                        xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"         m:DataServiceVersion="3.0">
    <Schema 
        xmlns:cg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/codegeneration" 
        xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/Protocols/SAPData" 
        xmlns:rdl="http://www.sap.com/Protocols/SAPData/RDL" 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" 
        xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" Namespace="app2">
        <ComplexType Name="ApplicationView">
            <Property Name="__ID" Type="Edm.Int64" Nullable="false"/>
        </ComplexType>
        <EntityType Name="test1_entityType">
            <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="__ID"/>
            </Key>
            <Property Name="__ID" Type="Edm.Int64" Nullable="false"/>
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="test2_entityType">
            <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="__ID"/>
            </Key>
            <Property Name="__ID" Type="Edm.Int64" Nullable="false"/>
        </EntityType>
        <EntityContainer Name="__container" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
            <EntitySet Name="test1" EntityType="app2.test1_entityType"/>
            <EntitySet Name="test2" EntityType="app2.test2_entityType"/>
            <FunctionImport Name="action1" IsSideEffecting="true" IsBindable="true" rdl:source-object="action">
                <Parameter Name="bindingParam" Type="app2.test1_entityType"/>
            </FunctionImport>
            <FunctionImport Name="action2" IsSideEffecting="true" IsBindable="true" rdl:source-object="action">
                <Parameter Name="bindingParam" Type="app2.test1_entityType"/>
            </FunctionImport>
            <FunctionImport Name="action3" IsSideEffecting="true" IsBindable="true" rdl:source-object="action">
                <Parameter Name="bindingParam" Type="app2.test2_entityType"/>
            </FunctionImport>
            <FunctionImport Name="action4" IsSideEffecting="true" IsBindable="true" rdl:source-object="action">
                <Parameter Name="bindingParam" Type="app2.test2_entityType"/>
            </FunctionImport>
            <FunctionImport Name="globalAction" IsSideEffecting="true" IsBindable="false" rdl:source-object="action"/>
            <FunctionImport Name="ApplicationView" IsSideEffecting="false" IsBindable="false" rdl:source-object="view">
                <ReturnType Type="Collection(ApplicationView)"/>
            </FunctionImport>
        </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
    <Schema 
        xmlns:cg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/codegeneration" 
        xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/Protocols/SAPData" 
        xmlns:rdl="http://www.sap.com/Protocols/SAPData/RDL" 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" 
        xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" Namespace="app2.metadataParent">
        <ComplexType Name="MyView">
            <Property Name="myElement" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="5000" Unicode="true"/>
        </ComplexType>
        <EntityType Name="MyEntity_entityType">
            <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="__ID"/>
            </Key>
            <Property Name="__ID" Type="Edm.Int64" Nullable="false"/>
            <Property Name="myElement" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="5000" Unicode="true"/>
        </EntityType>
        <EntityContainer Name="__container" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="false">
            <EntitySet Name="MyEntity" EntityType="app2.metadataParent.MyEntity_entityType"/>
            <FunctionImport Name="myAction" IsSideEffecting="true" IsBindable="true" rdl:source-object="action">
                <ReturnType Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="5000" Unicode="true"/>
                <Parameter Name="bindingParam" Type="app2.metadataParent.MyEntity_entityType"/>
            </FunctionImport>
            <FunctionImport Name="MyView" IsSideEffecting="false" IsBindable="false" rdl:source-object="view">
                <ReturnType Type="Collection(MyView)"/>
            </FunctionImport>
        </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
    <Schema 
        xmlns:cg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/codegeneration" 
        xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/Protocols/SAPData" 
        xmlns:rdl="http://www.sap.com/Protocols/SAPData/RDL" 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" 
        xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" Namespace="app2.metadataParent.metadata2Child">
        <EntityType Name="xxx_entityType">
            <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="__ID"/>
            </Key>
            <Property Name="__ID" Type="Edm.Int64" Nullable="false"/>
        </EntityType>
        <EntityContainer Name="__container" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="false">
            <EntitySet Name="xxx" EntityType="app2.metadataParent.metadata2Child.xxx_entityType"/>
            <FunctionImport Name="xxxyyy" IsSideEffecting="true" IsBindable="true" rdl:source-object="action">
                <Parameter Name="bindingParam" Type="app2.metadataParent.metadata2Child.xxx_entityType"/>
            </FunctionImport>
        </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
    <Schema 
        xmlns:cg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/codegeneration" 
        xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/Protocols/SAPData" 
        xmlns:rdl="http://www.sap.com/Protocols/SAPData/RDL" 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" 
        xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" Namespace="app2.metadataNotChild">
        <EntityType Name="ffgg_entityType">
            <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="__ID"/>
            </Key>
            <Property Name="__ID" Type="Edm.Int64" Nullable="false"/>
        </EntityType>
        <EntityContainer Name="__container" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="false">
            <EntitySet Name="ffgg" EntityType="app2.metadataNotChild.ffgg_entityType"/>
            <FunctionImport Name="gghh" IsSideEffecting="true" IsBindable="true" rdl:source-object="action">
                <Parameter Name="bindingParam" Type="app2.metadataNotChild.ffgg_entityType"/>
            </FunctionImport>
        </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
</edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

I tried to use also

```
   "//edmx:Edmx//edmx:DataServices//Schema/Namespace"
   "//edmx:Edmx//edmx:DataServices//Schema//Namespace"
```

Do you have any idea why I don't succeed to get any result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Schema` element has

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm"
```

which means it (and all its un-prefixed children) are in this namespace, and therefore will not be matched by `.../Schema` in an XPath expression (unprefixed names in XPath expressions always refer to an element in *no* namespace).

You need to supply a [`NamespaceContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html#setNamespaceContext%28javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext%29) to your `XPath` instances, telling them how to resolve prefixes to namespace URIs.  Unfortunately there's no default implementation of this interface available in the standard Java class library but there are third party implementations e.g. [SimpleNamespaceContext from the Spring Framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/xml/SimpleNamespaceContext.html), or it's fairly simple to create your own.  Using the Spring implementation as an example, it'd be something like this:

```
public class XPathUtils implements IXPath {

    private Document doc;
    private XPath xpath;
    private SimpleNamespaceContext nsCtx;

    public XPathUtils(String baseString) throws HanaHttpConnectivityException {
      // as before
      // .......
      xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
      nsCtx = new SimpleNamespaceContext();
      xpath.setNamespaceContext(nsCtx);
    }

    public Object getObjectValue(String strValue, String... namespaces) throws HanaHttpConnectivityException {
        try {
            if(namespaces != null) {
              // namespaces array is [prefix1, uri1, prefix2, uri2, ...]
              for(int i = 0; i < namespaces.length; i++) {
                nsCtx.bindNamespaceUri(namespaces[i], namespaces[++i]);
              }
            }
            XPathExpression xpathExp = xpath.compile(strValue);
            return xpathExp.evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            throw new HanaHttpConnectivityException(e);
        } finally {
            nsCtx.clear();
        }

    }
}
```

As well as providing a binding for the `edmx` prefix to `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx`, you will need to bind a prefix (e.g. `edm`) to the `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm` namespace and use that prefix in your XPath:

```
NodeList namespaceAttributes = (NodeList)xpathUtil.getObjectValue(
    "/edmx:Edmx/edmx:DataServices/edm:Schema/@Namespace",
      "edmx", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx",
      "edm",  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm");
```

Comment: Moreover the xml you provided is not valid: there should be a `</edmx:Edmx>` at the end of the file ...

Comment: I forgot to add the </edmx:Edmx>

Comment: I didn't understand what should be the path in this case to get value of schema for example Namespace or EntityType

Comment: @user1365697 `Namespace` is an attribute so (assuming the right NamespaceContext) something like `/edmx:Edmx/edmx:DataServices/edm:Schema/@Namespace` would give you a `NodeList` of all the `Namespace` attributes for the different `Schema` elements.  For _elements_ like `EntityType` you'd need to use the prefix you bound to `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm`, the same as for the `Schema` element.

Comment: I tried this /edmx:Edmx/edmx:DataServices/edm:Schema/@Namespace and it didn't work

Comment: Could we have a short chat ?

Comment: @user1365697 that should work _provided_ you have a properly configured NamespaceContext.

Comment: I tried this logic  Object commandValue = xpathUtil.getObjectValue("/edmx:Edmx/edmx:DataServices/edm:Schema/Namespace");

Comment: What did you mean in configured NamespaceContext ? How I can do it ? What is should be in this case ?

Comment: @user1365697 I've provided an example of how you could do it with the Spring `SimpleNamespaceContext`

Comment: thnaks but that is the type of SimpleNamespaceContext

Comment: @user1365697 it's the one whose JavaDoc I linked to in the previous paragraph.

Comment: for example  private SimpleNamespaceContext nsCtx and  nsCtx = new SimpleNamespaceContext();